# only one additional container should open / jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a website that shows a gallery of 8 images. If one clicks on one of the images the browser scroll down 650px and then another container (image + describing text) opens. A click on a button closes the additional information and the browser window moves up again. That works very well.

My question: 
If one block is already open and a user opens a second block, the class "ausklappen" should be removed from the first block in order to make it invisible again.

Thank you for ideas
Raphael

Link to develloppement area: http://homepage-4-you.net/andersicht/

My HTML: 
Gallery:

```
<ul class="wp-block-gallery columns-4 is-cropped galerie-schmal"> 
<li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src=„example.com“ alt="" /><figcaption>name 1 </figcaption></figure></li>
<li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src=„example.com“ alt="" /><figcaption>name 2 </figcaption></figure></li> 
    …
<li class="blocks-gallery-item"><figure><img src=„example.com“ alt="" /><figcaption>name 8 </figcaption></figure></li>
</ul>
```

8 additional blocks:

```
<div class="wp-block-media-text alignwide einzelportrait1 ausklappen“></div>
<div class="wp-block-media-text alignwide einzelportrait2 ausklappen“></div>
…
<div class="wp-block-media-text alignwide einzelportrait8 ausklappen“></div>
```

Button for going back:

```
<div class=„einzelportrait_button“> <img src=„examle.com“ alt=„“ /></div>
```

My jQuery:

1) scroll down and (eventually) scroll up again:

```
$(".blocks-gallery-item img").click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=650px'}, 800);
});

 $(".einzelportrait_button").click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '-=650px'}, 800);
});
```

2) Open blocks of additional information

```
$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(1)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait1" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });   

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(2)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait2" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });  

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(3)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait3" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });  

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(4)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait4" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });  

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(5)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait5" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });  

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(6)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait6" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });  

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(7)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait7" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });  

$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li:nth-child(8)" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( ".einzelportrait8" ).addClass( "ausklappen");
    });
```

3) Close additional information

```
$(".einzelportrait_button").click(function(){
        $(".einzelportrait1, .einzelportrait2, .einzelportrait3, .einzelportrait4, .einzelportrait5, .einzelportrait6, .einzelportrait7, .einzelportrait8").removeClass("ausklappen");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with `:nth-child` in this case will not be a simple way to do that .. instead you can work with `index()` it will be easier

1st: give the `einzelportrait1 , einzelportrait2  , einzelportrait3...` the same class like `einzelportrait` without numbers

```
<div class="wp-block-media-text alignwide einzelportrait ausklappen“></div>
```

2nd: in js use just one click event

```
$( "ul.wp-block-gallery li" ).on( "click", function() {
    var ThisIndex = $(this).index();
    $( ".einzelportrait.ausklappen").removeClass("ausklappen");
    $( ".einzelportrait:eq("+ThisIndex+")").addClass("ausklappen");
});
```

Comment: @rabox66 you're totally welcome.. Have a great day :-)